# How does fsolve in scipy work? What methods does it use to find the roots?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to find out how fsolve in scipy works. So far, all I have found is that it is a numerical solver that finds the root of non linear sets of equations. But I can't find what method it uses to find the roots anywhere. Does anyone know how the roots are found?

Comment: You can read its [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L41), for example.

Comment: Thanks, its still a little tame but atleast better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So, after looking up the source code it seems that the solver "fsolve" uses the powell method to find the roots.